# need to modify src in youtube iframe

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have problem with some regexp.
I'm trying to modify src of iframe, I need to add enablejsapi, if it doesn't exists.

```
preg_match('/<iframe[^>]+src=([\'"])?((?(1).+?|[^\s>]+))(?(1)\1)/', 
$model->video, $matches);
$src = $matches[2];
if(!strstr($src,"enablejsapi")){
    if(strstr($src, "?")){
        $src.="&enablejsapi=1";
    }else{
        $src.="?enablejsapi=1";
    }
}
```

I get it, but I couldn't put it back. I need it to controll video. something like `$("#player").stop();`

Comment: Could you provide a few examples of what code you're trying to (/to not) match, so I can see how your regex works exactly? Trying to decode something that complex, with such little context, isn't fun.

Comment: To check if it has `enablejsapi` or not, use Domdocument and parse_str, parse_url functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_match('#<iframe[^>]+src=([\'"])(.*)\1#isU', $model->video, $matches);
$src = $matches[2];
if(false === strstr($src, 'enablejsapi')){
    if(false !== strstr($src, '?')){
        $src.= '&enablejsapi=1';
    }else{
        $src.= '?enablejsapi=1';
    }
}
$model->video = preg_replace('#' . preg_quote($matches[2]) . '#', $src, $model->video);
```